# wpf image source change work after focus changed

Tags: wpf, image

I have wpf app with button, that should reflect two states - enabled/disabled.
The button have image as its content:

```
<Button Name="FindButton" Style="{StaticResource TextEditorToolbarButtonStyle}"
        Command="FindButtonCommand"
        Margin="2,0,10,0">

    <Image Name="FindSvgViewbox" Style="{StaticResource TextEditorToolbarIconStylePng}" 
                     Source="/Img/png/enabled/find.png"/>            
</Button>
```

So in some cases button will be disabled, and those image source will changed like this:

```
 FindSvgViewbox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(disabledImagePath));
```

This works, but image actualy change only after i click on some other control like textboxt or other button, so there is some kind of lag or delay.
What can cause the problem?

**EDIT:**

Here is style for button:

```
 <Style x:Key="TextEditorToolbarButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderThickness="0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C5C5C5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

The image source changed in `CanExecuteChanged` handler for button:

```
 FindButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(DoFind, o => FindCanExecute);
            FindButtonCommand .CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                AppUtils.ChangeIconSource(FindButton, FindSvgViewbox);
            };
```

Comment: Maybe you have some problems in your `TextEditorButtonStyle`. And can you show your code, where you change source of image?

Comment: Thanks for reply, edited the question with more details

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you should invalidate command bindings after some actions, that make your button become enabled/disabled. You should use `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` to update bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image source is only depends on enabled/disabled state of button (which is `IsEnabled` property), you can control image source value with pure XAML. Your *TextEditorToolbarIconStylePng* style should be like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TextEditorToolbarIconStylePng" TargetType="Image">

    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Img/png/enabled/find.png" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Img/png/enabled/findDisabled.png" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Note that initial `Source` value should be assigned from style's `Setter` rather than from `Image` element directly, and of course you shouldn't edit `Source` value from code.

Also note that this style uses *image's* `IsEnabled` property, which is by default inherited from *button's* `IsEnabled` property (controlled by command), unless you will manually edit image's property.

Comment: Thanks, this approach solved the issue, now images updates fast without need to click to another control